# Prepopulate slug field from Foreign Key in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, slug

How would I go about prepopulating a slug from a foreign key? Here are how some of my models are setup:

```
Class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField() 

class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title)
    number = models.IntegerField(help_text="Do not include the '#'.")
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

admin.py:

```
class IssueAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):      
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}    
admin.site.register(Issue, IssueAdmin)
```

What the Issue prepopulates is the ID of the foreign key, but I suppose I would need it to preopulate the slug of the foreign key. How would I go about doing this? I am using Django 1.3. I have checked other threads, but they seem to refer to version of Django a few years older that don't work anymore.

I need the Titles to display the list of issues. So far, it works. And you can click on the link to the issue to see what the issue displays.

I feel as if reworking the Title to abstract classes the way Skidoosh will not allow me to view subsets of objects....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the docs (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) it does state that you can't reference a foreign key field.

Looking at you design would this not work better:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Issue(BaseModel):
    number = models.IntegerField(help_text="Do not include the '#'.")

class ComicBookSeries(BaseModel):
    issues = models.ForeignKey(Issue)
```

You need to declare the classes in that order!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wait, would doing this Parent to Child model allow me to show a list of Titles that Issue is related to?

Comment: Can you give me a quick example of the problem your trying to solve? I should be able to guide you from that.

Comment: Ahhhhh! I get it! I'll pop it in as an answer!

Comment: Edited! I thought you were building an Issue as in problem tracker!